# Following Logic and Relationships Through when Deleting/Editing a Core Data Object

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, editing

My application has two entities:

- People
- Contract

Related like so:

- One person can have many contracts.
- A contract can only be held by one person.

I've got the basic application working with the creating of Core Data information to display this in a table view. I am confused about what to do in certain situations, like renaming People.

Suppose Person A has Contract A and Person B has Contract B. If I rename Person A to Person C, then automatically Contract A is assigned to Person C, and therefore Person A does not have any contracts and so should not exist anymore.

How do I achieve that efficiently?

In my app, I have two table view controllers in a tab bar, the first consists of the Contracts as section headers and the People names as the row text label. The second tab consists of no sections, but just rows of people names.

If in the first table view, I have Person A under Contract A and then I go in and rename Person A to Person C, then when the detailViewController saves and the table refreshes, I will see Contract A assigned to Person C successfully and Person A removed.

However, if I go to the People tab, I will still see Person A but I will now also see Person C. Person C, when I click on it shows me Contract A, but Person A has no records when I click on it and should therefore be deleted.

A few things to note:

1) If Person A has OTHER contracts then it should not of course be deleted. 
2) I'm using NSManagedObject Subclasses for Person and Contracts
3) Contracts Tab is using Contracts Entity in the NSFetchedResultsController and People Tab is using People Entity in its NSFetchedResultsController. 
4) Originally both sides of my relationship were set to Nullify but I tried this with Cascade on one side and then both sides with the same results.

I don't have any code at this point because I'm honestly not sure how to tackle this particular scenario (keeping in mind, everything else is working well up to this point).

Comment: Please provide code demonstrating how you are performing this renaming of Person A to Person C. Also, please describe how you are feeding data to the `UITableView`: Are you using an `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Comment: Hi Jeremy - thanks for the reply - absolutely, using a NSFRC and the code to rename is:     self.person = (People *)[People peopleCreation:self.nameTF.text inManagedObjectContext:context];
    self.contract.whoFor = self.person;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you try to accomplish, but ...

It seems that what you are doing is not "renaming" but "re-assigning" a contract to a new user.
Meaning, you are creating "Person C" and assign "Contact A" to it.

I'm not sure what is the behaviour you try to implement.

If you like a `Person` with no `Contract`s simply to **not appear** in your view controller, 
but still exist in your store, you will need the following:
In your "person view controller" use this predicate for the [fetched results controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSPredicate* p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contracts.@count != 0"];
```

if you like to delete a `Person` with no `Contract`s you will need to add custom logic.
This might look something like:

```
//This goes in your `Person` entity implementation file
- (BOOL) validateForUpdate:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    if (![self hasFaultForRelationshipNamed:@"contracts"] && [self.contracts count] == 0) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self];
    }
    return [super validateForUpdate:error];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan - my apologies that was confusing but with your predicate code, that worked like a charm. I'm thinking about deploying the deleting method I may not do that because I have an autocomplete table view that appears beneath the text field, so users may find it convenient to have an already typed named in there, even if currently there are no contracts for that user. It works with one entry - so I change the name on one user who has one contract, but the moment I change it on one user that has two contracts - so re-assign the names, it crashes

Comment: with: CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification. - I'm not using that Notification but I will be putting in breakpoints to find out what's going on here.. thanks again for your help on this one! Apart from the crash, this is working exactly how I'd expect and how my users would too!

Comment: Also, can I just confirm the proper deletion rules are in place on the model - Person -> Contracts (cascade) and Contracts -> Person (Nullify)?

Comment: Your cascade rules looks reasonable if a contract may not exist when it is not assigned to a person. without looking at your re-assignment code and model structure it is difficult to say what cause the exception (i think it is related to the fetched results controller operation).